# A little stumped with some code for class

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm a little stumped with an assignment for class. So I'm supposed to take four user inputs for different hotels and have different prices. I'm having trouble with some of my If statements. When I test my program say I put "A" I get an error saying uninitialized constant C (NameError). I'm just looking to see if the user puts A,B,C, or D and then go on to do the rest of the if statement. I'm wondering if I did something wrong with my if statements. Here is my code.

```
choice1 = gets.chomp.capitalize.to_s

if choice1 == C then 
  puts "For how many nights?"
  nightsC == gets.chomp.to_i

  if nightsC == 3
    priceC == 700
    nightsT + nightsC
  else
    priceC == nightsC * 300
  end
end
```

Here's the Pastebin https://pastebin.com/9c5ezuab

Comment: Please edit the question and provide the code in the body of the question. Off-site links are strongly discouraged: They can drift out of sync, be at untrusted sites, contain inappropriate content, or expire.

Comment: Only provide the relevant code of course:)

Comment: Alright. I've edited with the code in question

Comment: `C` is a class, `"C"` is a string which is what `gets` will return.

Comment: Practice safe indentation. It'll help you understand the logic of your own code. Decent text editors will indent for you. Your future self will thank you. And write Ruby according to Ruby's style, not as if it's Python. Your first code review writing it as you are would be painful.

Comment: @theTinMan I edited and fixed the indentation at the same time you posted the comment :) Good advice none the less!

Comment: Please read "[mcve]" along with the linked pages. Your code isn't valid and is rejected by the Ruby interpreter. As such the question needs to be closed. We need code that doesn't have syntax errors.

Comment: I was just wondering why it had been flagged to be closed.

Comment: @Confused_Student, are `A`, `B`, `C` or `D` supposed to be keys that were pressed, or defined classes? Your question isn't asked well and needed editing and explanation of what you're trying to do otherwise it's doomed to be closed.

Answer (score 2):

You are referencing an undefined class, `C`, which is why you get a `NameError`. If you defined `C` as a class you will not get the error. However `gets` will returns an instance of String, such as `"C"`, not a class. Your syntax is wrong.

```
# assignment
choice1 = "C"

# equality
choice1 == C # => NameError 

# define class
class C
end

# equality
choice1 == C # => false (no error this time)
choice1 == "C" # => true
```

By the way, technically `C` is not the syntax for a class but a constant. For example you could do any of the following to define the `C` constant.

```
C = "hello"
C = Class.new
class C; end
```

Comment: `C` isn't a class, the OP is trying to check the value of a string literal. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256328/vote-to-close-unclear-questions-immediately-after-commenting and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260263/how-long-should-we-wait-for-a-poster-to-clarify-a-question-before-closing. While you're trying to help it's better to help the site and the user by closing than struggling to fix it.

Comment: I think the reverse. `C` is an undefined class / constant and I see no string literal. Hence the answer that the OP is using `C` not `"C"`... But I see the point of the links above. It seems pretty clear in this case the problem and solution since we know `gets` returns a string.

Comment: If you look at the linked code in the question, there is repeated use of bare upper-case characters `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` being compared to a value that results from the use of `gets` and no attempt to create any classes.

Comment: Exactly my point. I think they are using `C` instead of a string literal, `"C"`, as per my answer.